# Некорректная работа Qlabel

Tags: c++, qt

Есть вот такой фрагмент кода

```
QLabel* lbl = new QLabel;
QFont f("Helvetica", 100, QFont::Bold);
lbl->setFont(f);
QString winString = "<FONT COLOR = GREEN><CENTER>ПРАВИЛЬНО!!!</CENTER><FONT>";
lbl->setText(winString);
int NumberLine = 1;
QString String1 = ui->lineEdit_1->text();
if(ControlCode(String1, NumberLine))
{
    //если введенное слово правильное
    lbl->show();
    Sleep(4000);
    lbl->hide();
}
```

Если убрать в конце фрагмента `Sleep и lbl->hide()`, то надпись отображается, как ей и следует. Если указанные строки не убирать, окно для `lbl` соответствующего размера отображается, а надписи в нем нет. Просто нет. Я не могу понять, в чем прикол. Я начинающий, если какой-то очевидный косяк не заметил, не серчайте.

UPD:

Решил я вопрос с окном. Через поток в котором таймер. Теперь окно появляется ровно на столько сколько мне надо и благополучно по завершению работы таймера закрывается.

Код для процесса, который будет внедрен в новый поток из основного потока и в том же хэдере прописан класс самого потока.

```
#ifndef CONGRA_H
#define CONGRA_H


#pragma once

#include <QtWidgets>

class Congra : public QObject {
Q_OBJECT

signals:
    void hiding();

public:
    QTimer m_timer;
    Congra(QObject* pobj = 0) : QObject(pobj)
    {
        connect(&m_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), SLOT(hideSignal()));
    }
    void startShow(int seconds)
    {
        m_timer.start(seconds);
    }
    public slots:
    void hideSignal()
    {
        emit hiding();
    }
};

class MyThread : public QThread {
Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyThread(){}

    void run()
    {
        exec();
    }
};

#endif // CONGRA_H
```

и фрагмент кода из потока предка

1.Коннект

```
QObject::connect(&timerMessage, SIGNAL(hiding()), SLOT(HideWindow()));
```

2.сам вызов процесса дочернего потока

```
timerMessage.startShow(1500);
```

3.И слот, прописанный в хэдере класса потока предка

```
public slots:
    void HideWindow()
    {
        lbl->hide();
    }
```

Comment: То есть вы хотите сказать, что надписи нет сразу, а не спустя 4 секунды?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, надпись не появляется вовсе. Просто пустое окно появляется и спустя указанное в Sleep время исчезает. А без Sleep и lbl->hide() появлется практически сразу и окно и надпись.
Если что, у меня Qt5.5.1 VS2012

Comment: Хм... Мистика какая-то, вроде все правильно. Попробуйте перед hide вывести через printf/QMessageBox значение lbl->text().

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов. Мистика продолжается )
Вставил после Sleep строку 

QMessageBox::information(0, "Information", lbl->text());

Как только выскочил месседжбокс, сразу же отобразилась надпись и в QLabel.  lbl->text соответствует заданному.
Что это может быть?

Comment: Если ДО MessageBox ее нет, а с его появлением надпись появляется - что-то с обновлением окна... Поток у вас точно(!) один?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, второй я точно не создавал, я до этого еще просто не доучился. У меня создается впечатление, что компилятор каким-то образом оптимизирует код. Но терзают сомнения, что за оптимизация такая, своевольная что ли.

Comment: Не, скорее дело в обновлении. Кстати, а на ЧЕМ у вас Qlabel располагается? И попробуйте передать "родителя" в конструктор.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, ввиду отсутствия необходимого опыта хочу уточнить, что означает "на чем" и передать родителя чего(qlabel объекта?)

Comment: Какое окно лежит под QLabel? QDialog там или QMainWindow?

Comment: а, понял - QMainWindow

Comment: Ну вот он и есть "родитель", попробуйте типа такого QLabel* lbl = new QLabel(mainWndPtr); сделать.

Comment: Написал так, 
QLabel* lbl = new QLabel(MainWindow);
выдает ошибку: "'MainWindow' : illegal use of this type as an expression"
У меня окно так и называется MainWindow.
Еще, для информации, у меня QLabel создается и используется внутри слота(клик по кнопке) в объекте MainWindow.

Comment: Все совсем плохо?

Answer (score 1):

При вызове метода `show()` создается событие, которое добавляется в очередь событий, далее ваш поток засыпает и затем создает новое событие для скрытия виджета. После завершения метода основной поток получает возможность обработать очередь событий и поэтому `label` по сути показывается и скрывается одновременно. Есть 2 варианта решения данной проблемы:

1. После вызова метода `show()` выполнить принудительную обработку событий с помощью `qApp->processEvents()`. Но это не самое лучшее решение.
2. Вынести участок кода, блокирующий основной поток, в отдельный поток. В этом случае не будет проблем с обновлением GUI приложения.

Comment: спасибо. Надеюсь,  вы мне раскрыли глаза. А то я уже три дня пытаюсь победить эту проблему и не знал даже в каком направлении копать. Если получится, отпишусь.

Comment: Спасибо, получилось. В отдельном потоке реализован только один таймер и он работает. Сорри, что сразу не ответил. UPDATE в вопросе.